# a11y: What is the correct `<track>` element for video chats?

Tags: reactjs, html5-video, accessibility, eslint

I'm building a video chat app with React.

When I'm using the `<video />` element my [ESLint plugin for writing accessible UI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y) yells at me that a `<track />` element is missing.

Code:

```js
function Video({ autoPlay, playsInline, videoEl }) {
  return <video autoPlay={autoPlay} playsInline={playsInline} ref={videoEl} />;
}
```

Warning:

```
error  Media elements such as <audio> and <video> must have a <track> for captions  jsx-a11y/media-has-caption
```

After I looked up `<track />` it seems to expect a `src` attribute with `.vtt` file. But in a video chat, there are no captions. What would be the most accessible way to make a video chat's HTML accessible?

Comment: Do you have access to a voice translation API / is it scoped within the project? Live translation is different to having a `<track>` element.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Unfortunately, I do not :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can then perfectly ignore this message**

This refers to the WCAG Guideline : [Understanding Success Criterion 1.2.4: Captions (Live)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/captions-live.html)

The guideline specifically states that:

> This success criterion was intended to apply to broadcast of synchronized media and **is not intended to require that two-way multimedia calls between two or more individuals through web apps must be captioned** regardless of the needs of users.

Comment: Hey, any chance you can remove that last line 'If you just want to satisfy eslint' - adding an empty `track` to satisfy a linter is an awful idea, doing ANYTHING to satisfy a linter over real world usability is a bad idea. In this example an empty track gets announced in a screen reader and in certain off the shelf video players it will trigger the captions button to be shown.  I don't want to just go edit your answer as I find that rude.

Comment: Another way to “satisfy” eslint that communicates intent better and won’t confuse AT, would be to [use inline comments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments) to disable carping about that rule.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie In fact, I perfectly agree. I did not want to add "/s" after that "suggestion"...

Comment: hehe, the problem with the written word, no tone so I can't detect sarcasm, does that mean i get an r/whoosh :-)